# Python error while applying plot confusion matrix

Tags: python

how can I solve this error?

scores=[[],[],[]]

models=[]

def plot_confusion_matrix (model,model_name,scores,models):

def plot_confusion_matrix (model,model_name,scores,models):
File "/var/folders/z5/1bkxlz2x21112m3g5f8s4rbm0000gn/T/ipykernel_1992/1084257382.py", line 1
def plot_confusion_matrix (model,model_name,scores,models):
^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

solve error

def plot_confusion_matrix (model,model_name,scores,models): File "/var/folders/z5/1bkxlz2x21112m3g5f8s4rbm0000gn/T/ipykernel_1992/1084257382.py", line 1 def plot_confusion_matrix (model,model_name,scores,models): ^ IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Your code is very unclear so its very hard for someone to answer your question. However it seems to be one of these two issues:

1. You are trying to define a function and have missed indenting your code after definining it. In Python, indents are a part of a syntax and if your code is not correctly indented, it will lead to errors. This can be fixed the following way:

```py
scores=[[],[],[]]
    
models=[]
    
def plot_confusion_matrix(model,model_name,scores,models):
    # Your code(after an indent)
```

2. You are trying to call the function. In this case you dont need to use a def and colon but just the function name with any parameters in parenthesis. This can be fixed the following way:

```py
plot_confusion_matrix(model,model_name,scores,models)
```